# Changing look and feel of that popup box(window which we open to choose file from computer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As far my knowledge we can't change the UI of file popup box(window which we open to choose file from computer).

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="pic">
</form>
```

I know we can't do that however, is there any way we can change look and feel of that popup box(window).

For better standing I have attached the image of window of the file upload pop box.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No! you can not, that is managed by Operating system**, and we can control only browser(if browser allow this by JavaScript APIs/HTML/CSS).

---

There is only one tricky way, to design our own file-browsing by JavaScript, but that can raise security problems and all browser set it disabled by default.

On such type of JavaScript browser ask from user to allow access to local file system each time(per browsing session). *I suggest you not to do so, you should use it on local system for study purpose only.*

One more thing that will also not work on all devices/OSs/Browsers. (Once I have accessed local drive by JavaScript ON internet explorer and windows 7 OS, I am not sure about others.)